# Dpkg .deb file - Not a debian format

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, cuda

I'm new at Linux, so the following question may sound trivial. At the moment I want to install a .deb file, specifically the `Cuda Toolbox 8.0`, and it uses a .deb file. However, when I use the command

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
```

I obtain the following log:

```
dpkg-deb: error: 'cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb.deb
```

The solution looks quite trivial, since it is a standard procedure to install .deb packages and it is written in the nVidia tutorial. But I'm not able to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you might want to check the file download properly. Confirm with source checksum or file size

Comment: Looks like a known problem: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/993274/bad-checksum-for-cuda-8-0-for-ubuntu-14-04/.

Comment: Is the file named `cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb.deb`? If so, try renaming it so it only has one .deb at the end, and see if it works now.

Comment: I'm downloading again the file. As @mikewhatever mentioned, it looks like a known problem: the checksum didn't match. The inconvenience is though the size of the file.

Comment: As silly as it sounds, I accidentally downloaded a ***tar.gz*** file and tried to install it using dpkg -i instead of the ***.deb*** one. Caution, beginners!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error happens when your deb file is broken. Check if you have downloaded properly (use md5 or sha checksum).

I just had this error when I was trying to install a deb file when its download wasn't finished yet.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i rocketchat_2.9.0_amd64.deb 
dpkg-deb: error: 'rocketchat_2.9.0_amd64.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive rocketchat_2.9.0_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rocketchat_2.9.0_amd64.deb
```