# apt-offline_1.8.2-1_all.deb "not a debian format archive" error

Tags: apt, 20.04

My network is not working on Linux box.
I downloaded apt-offline from https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/apt-offline/download
Copied it to ubuntu
I've run checksum which seems to be fine.

```
$ shasum apt-offline_1.8.2-1_all.deb 
9584d3d68492b17c01994f9c9fe2775f979ddcba  apt-offline_1.8.2-1_all.deb
```

Ran this command

```
sudo dpkg -i apt-offline_1.8.2-1_all.deb
```

It gave error not a debian format archive

How to fix this issue or how to get correct apt-offline?

Comment: Did you copy it from the USB to your Ubuntu computer? Sometimes the USB will be mounted without permissions.

Comment: Yes I copied from USB to ubuntu.

Comment: @Nmath I verified and it checks out.

Comment: @Nmath It's listed [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/apt-offline/download#pdownloadmeta)

Comment: @Raymond Can you please copy and paste the error.

Comment: Thanks @mchid for clarifying I was just going to write same comment.

Comment: @mchid how do I copy n paste all error from a PC which is offline?  The error is something like - not a debian format archive

Comment: It's just that there might be something we're missing in the output besides the error alone. The output contains a few other things like in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896856/dpkg-deb-file-not-a-debian-format). Since the shasum is fine, it looks like we need a bit more info. As of now we don't know if the info would be helpful or not because we haven't seen it.

Comment: The other thing I would suggest would be to try using `apt` instead. It's worth a shot: `sudo apt install ./apt-offline_1.8.2-1_all.deb` Just don't forget the `./` or it won't work because you have to specify the path to the file.

Comment: I'll try this command, I've seen that post and many other posts. Have wasted full day on it.

Comment: That or try downloading it again. It should have the wrong shasum if that's the problem but who knows? Maybe try a different method/browser to download the file?

Answer (score 0):

If the shasum is good, I don't know why it's not installing. However, there is a dirty hack you can use to install the files manually. You will need to extract the deb package and then copy the files to your system. Unfortunately, `dpkg` and `apt` will not know the package is installed so eventually, you will have to fix this problem or manually install future updates.

---

**First**, create a working directory and move the deb file into the directory:

```
mkdir apt-offline
mv apt-offline_1.8.2-1_all.deb ./apt-offline
cd apt-offline
```

---

**Then**, extract the files using the `dpkg-deb` command like this:

```
dpkg-deb -xv apt-offline_1.8.2-1_all.deb
```

*Alternatively*, if `dpkg-deb` is not installed (command not found), you can use `ar` and `tar` to extract the files instead:

```
ar xvf apt-offline_1.8.2-1_all.deb
tar xvf dat*
```

---

**After you extract the files**, use the following command to copy the files into your system:

```
sudo cp -R ./usr/* /usr/
```

To verify the installation, run the following command:

```
which apt-offline
```

and it should return: `/usr/bin/apt-offline`

---

Aside from the fact that you won't get automatic updates, the other problem is that you won't have bash completion.

Comment: Again, this method is not recommended but if you've tried everything else, you can use this workaround as a last resort option.